# Why does Apache remove prefork settings when I copy and account from another server?

Tags: apache-2.2

I noticed something weird. It might be a bug. When I copy an account from another server, using whm, some apache settings just disapear, like prefork settings, max clients, etc...

What could I do to avoid this?

Comment: prefork settings and maxclients aren't per-account settings, they're per-server settings.  Of course they aren't going to transfer when you move an account.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *real* way to do this is to not use any web-based admin tools (which I guess whm is). If you would copy over the actual configuration files and adapt them, this wouldn't happen.